# How to configure IntelliJ IDEA comment shortcut to not go to next line?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

IntelliJ IDEA's keyboard shortcut for commenting, `Ctrl+/`, moves the cursor to the next line after it comments out the line. Is it possible to configure it so that it stays on the same line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Advanced Settings, and toggle `Move caret down after Comment with Line Comment action` in the Editor section

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283756#focus=Comments-27-5579465.0-0